# AngularJS retain search result data after navigating to different path

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a simple movie search (API call) with a link to movie info when you click title however when I view the info and go back to the result page the result data is not present anymore. I've thought of using `$location.search()` and fetch the same data whatever is in the URL parameter but that means it will call the API again (not what I'm after).

Is there a way to retain the data after navigating to a different path and back to the result page without calling the API again?

**Fixed using service**: --

```
angular
.module("myApp")
.factory('itemService', [...) {
    var basketArray = [];
    var savedData;

    return {

        saveSearched: function(data) {
            savedData = data;
        },

        getSavedData: function() {
            return savedData;
        }
   }]);
```

Controller:-

```
itemService.newSearchProducts(searchData)
 .then(function (response) {
    itemService.saveSearched(response);
 }
```

Comment: you could store your data in a service

Comment: How do you go back? With a button or backspace?

Comment: You can use ng-init directive and call a function like this ng-int="myfunction()", inside that function make a call to API.So whenever the page is refreshed the API will be called and data will be available.

Comment: @hurricane with a button.

Comment: @NitsanBaleli how exactly?

Comment: @RohanKawade was hoping to avoid recalling the API.

Comment: Then you should go with  @NitsanBaleli's  suggestion. Angular services are singleton in nature.So once the data is stored in the service you can use it throughout the application .

Comment: but how the page/service know if you've changed route from movie info back to movies (results)?

Comment: Nvm I think i've solved it :)